# counting number of string occurrences

Tags: lua

I'm trying to count the number of times that " --" occurs in a string.

So for instance, it occurs twice here 'a --b --c'

I tried the following, but it gives me 4 instead of 2, any idea why?

```
argv='a --b --c'
count = 0
for i in string.gfind(argv, " --") do
   count = count + 1
end
print(count)
```

Comment: In Lua 5.1 and up you need to use string.gmatch instead of string.gfind

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-` character has special meaning in patterns, used for a non-greedy repetition.

You need to escape it, i.e. use the pattern `" %-%-"`.

Answer (score 38):

you can actually do this as a one-liner using `string.gsub`:

```
local _, count = string.gsub(argv, " %-%-", "")
print(count)
```

no looping required!

Not recommended for large inputs, because the function returns the processed input to the `_` variable, and will hold onto the memory until the variable is destroyed.

Comment: Instead of using a dummy variable, [select](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-select) can discard the first returned value, the string with substitutions, which reduces the memory footprint.

Answer (score 18):

This snippet could be helpful, based on response of [Mike Corcoran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1208078/mike-corcoran) & optimisation suggestion of [WD40](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043033/wd40)

```
function count(base, pattern)
    return select(2, string.gsub(base, pattern, ""))
end

print(count('Hello World', 'l'))
```